# Geometric arithmetic: triangular number triples

Tags: triangles, relations

Call a triple $x, y,$ and $z$ of numbers triangular if and only if there is a triangle whose sides are in the triple ratio $x:y:z$. Since the sum of two sides of a triangle exceeds the remaining side, it is clear that if triple $x, y,$ and $z$ of numbers is triangular, then $x + y > z$ , $y + z  > x,$ and $z + x > y$ . Is the converse true?

Comment: If the answer is affirmative, we need a proof of the following proposition:
if triple x, y, z of numbers satisfies the condition (x + y) > z & (y + z ) > x & (z + x) > y, then it is triangular.

Comment: If the answer is negative, we need a counterexample: a triple x, y, z of numbers satisfying the condition (x + y) > z & (y + z ) > x & (z + x) > y, but not triangular. 

In this case we can ask how the condition can be strengthened to be sufficient for triangularity.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Without loss of generality, suppose that $z$ is the longest of the three numbers. Draw a line segment $AB$ having length $z$. Now draw circles with radii $x$ and $y$ centred at $A$ and $B$ respectively. These circles will intersect at points $P$ and $Q$. The triangles $PAB$ and $PAQ$ have side lengths $x,y,z$.

Comment: Théophile, where is the hypothesis used?

Comment: @johncorcoran Indeed, that's the crux of the construction. How do you know the two circles intersect?

Comment: @JOHNCORCORAN Also note that it isn't strictly necessary to assume that $z$ is the largest number; it just simplifies the proof slightly. When it comes time to draw the circles, suppose that they don't intersect. Then either the circles are far away from each other, implying that $x+y<z$, or one of the circles is inside the other. Can you take it from there?

Comment: @JOHNCORCORAN In your proposed edit, you commented: "The assumption that $z$ is the longest side is not only useless but unwarranted: there are equilateral triangles." First, it is not useless to call $z$ the largest number, since doing so simplifies the proof. As I mentioned, it isn't *strictly necessary* to make this assumption, but we might as well. Next, you say that it is unwarranted. Again, not so: even in equilateral triangles, we can still suppose that $z$ is the largest number; it just turns out that all three numbers are the largest. A similar case holds for isosceles triangles.